# Feature Request: Option to send all subscription results in one email

Tags: feature-request, email, subscription

After subscribing to a number of topics on stackoverflow.com, I now get numerous emails, each having questions related to one topic.

Is there a way I can receive one combined email containing all new questions in any of the tags that I subscribed to?